# Oracle APEX region width

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have two regions on my page side by side. The width of each region is automatically 50% or 6 columns each. I wanted to make right region to be only about 20% or 2-3 columns, while making the left region 9-10 columns. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using a grid-based theme like the Universal Theme, simply set the first regions' Column Span to 2 or 3 and the second's to 8 or 9!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set region's "Custom attributes" property to (for example)

- region 1: `style="width:400px"`
- region 2: `style="width:200px"`

and see how it behaves. Adjust it if necessary.

Comment: Try `style="width:70%"` - it is valid, but I *think* it'll set region size to 70% of its original size (not 70% of the whole screen).